# User feedback on Sentry Report Dialog not submitting

Tags: javascript, django, sentry, raven

I am running a Django server, along with a self-hosted Sentry server.  I tried adding a call on my 500.html template to collect [user feedback](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/learn/user-feedback/).

The sentry server correctly receives the initial 500 error, but does not receive the user feedback.  I see in my javascript console a 404 error after clicking "Submit Crash Report" when trying to send a POST to django.mydomain.com/api/embed/error-page/?eventId=abcde...&dsn=%2F%2Fzxy...%40sentry.mydomain.com%2F2

Before this, there is a successful GET request to sentry.mydomain.com/api/embed/error-page/?eventId=....

Here is the trace of the error:

```
POST "http://django.mydomain.com/api/embed/error-page/?eventId=b96e57dcb… 404 (Not Found)
dsn=%2F%2F8d64f9e...%40sentry.mydomain.com%2F2".
(anonymous function) @ raven.js:703
SentryErrorEmbed.submit @ ?eventId=b96e57d…&dsn=%2F%2F8d64f9e…%40sentry.mydoma…:139
_submitBtn.onclick @ ?eventId=b96e57d…&dsn=%2F%2F8d64f9e…%40sentry.mydoma…:65
```

Is it trying to send to the wrong domain?  How do I fix this or further investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Sentry 8.0.5, and I upgraded to 8.5.1. This resolved my issue.